# PHP,MYSQL, How to create validation for date, which is we cannot input the date that already been input in database

Tags: php, mysql, validation, date

- I'm using php and mysql database
- I'm doing my project of ballroom reservation
- I'm using datepicker at my booking reservation form

I try to do/how to do?

- if else/validation; which is if the date that I already input in database will cannot be input same date at the second time.

Can anyone help me how code it?

```
<?php


include 'connection.php';

$date = $_POST['date'];
$rand = rand ();
session_start();
$_SESSION['random']=$rand;
$type = $_POST['typeofballroom'];
$setup = $_POST['setup'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$conNum = $_POST['contactnumber'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$themes = $_POST['theme'];
$menu = $_POST['menu'];
$note = $_POST['notes'];



    $query = "SELECT * FROM ballroom_form WHERE date = '$date' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);




    $person = mysql_fetch_array($result);



    if($date == $person['date']) {
    echo "unvalid refference number";

    }


    else
    {
    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO ballroom_form  (`ID`,`random_number`,`ballroom_type`,`set_up`,`date`,`name`,`contact_number`,`email`,`themes`,`menu`,`note`) VALUES (NULL,'$rand','$type','$setup','$date','$name','$conNum','$email','$themes','$menu','$note')") or die(mysql_error());
   echo "user has been added";
   header ('location: randomNum.php');
   }



?>
```

it still when i input same date, it still proceed to ELSE. . . i have check all the form name, date name, database attribute, no typo no problem.

Comment: Table column with date must be unique, and you must 

1. Check if its already in table

2. Handle duplicate entry

Comment: thank you i got it unique. . . it work but its give me an error, can you give some example i i want to make it nice, don't want it view the duplicate entry error

Comment: @DmitryBezik : thank you i got it unique. . . it work but its give me an error, can you give some example i i want to make it nice, don't want it view the duplicate entry error

Answer (score 1):

Before insert into database, create a function which return bolean value and Check if that user entered date is already in database or not,if function return true it means date is already in database so display message to user otherwise do insert.
Pseudo code will be

```
If(checkdateindatabase())
(
  //show error to user
)
Else (
  Do inset
)
```

Comment: Or query for all locked dates in a range and check if given date is in results. This could help with providing suggested alternatives available. Also, a decent scheduler with locked appointment times should make it visible in the date form what is still available, rather than having user try over and over

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in steps.

1. Check to see if the date chosen by the user already exists in the database.
2. If it doesn't exist, continue with the script and make the reservation.
3. If the date already exists, echo out an appropriate error.

Be sure to use MySQLi or PDO prepared statements instead of the now deprecated mysql_* functions. This link explains the basics, and provides links for other readings. http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

Comment: TQ for the info but still i don't get it, i have provide and update my question i have put my code, still does't work please check my code tQ ^_^

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question, here is answer.
In database where you have created table from date. That you can make unique .
or other solution is that you can do coding such a way that it can't submit duplicate date.
like when somebody post form now your date is in
for example.

$sql ="Select *from table where date= '$variable1'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) ;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    foreach ($row as $value) 
{
echo "please use other date";

```
}

}
if(empty($value))
{
header('location:yourpage.php');
exit();
}
```

?>
by this you can check if somebody not using same date..

Comment: $sql ="Select *from table where date= '$variable1'"
thank you its work!